# Yii2: findAll() shows "1" instead of rows

Tags: php, yii2

I have a table called `color_person` with three columns: `id` (unique), `id_color`, `id_person`. It has around 100 rows.

I need to find all `id_person` that has `id_color` equal to 5.

```
$idPersons = ColorPerson::findall(['id_color' => 5]);
print_r($idPersons);
```

But this code shows: `1`. And it should shows rows. Sometimes the number one means the execution was good (like true). But I don't think this is the problem.

I have been reading [Active Record](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html) and it seems to be easy but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Start by changing `print_r($idPersons);` to `var_dump($idPersons);`. What does that print?

Comment: in your code block, `findall()` should be `findAll()`

Comment: try with     $idPersons = ColorPerson::find()->where(['id_color' => 5])         ->all();

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to see the data:

```
 <?php var_dump($idPersons); ?>
```

to view all data.